# A trigonometry equation: $3 \sin^2 \theta + 5 \sin \theta \cos \theta - 2\cos^2 \theta = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

> $$3 \sin^2 \theta + 5 \sin \theta \cos \theta - 2\cos^2 \theta = 0$$

What are the steps to solve this equation for $ \theta $?

Because, I  am always unable to deal with the product $\sin \theta \cos \theta$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please provide more context: what have you tried, where did you find this equation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try dividing by $\cos^2\theta$ all the equation...

Comment: that would create fractions and then again, the same story.

Comment: No, everything would be in terms of the tangent function and can be solve as a quadratic equation.

Comment: oh snap. you're right!

Answer (score 1):

Use the linearisation formulae (inverse of the duplication formulae):
\begin{align*}
&=3\frac{1-\cos2\theta}2+\frac52\sin2\theta-2\frac{1+\cos2\theta}2\\
&=\frac12-\frac52(\cos2\theta-\sin2\theta)=\frac12-\frac{5\sqrt 2}2\cos\Bigl(2\theta-\frac\pi4\Bigr),
\end{align*}
whence
\begin{align*}
3\sin^2\theta+&5\sin\theta\cos\theta-2\cos^2\theta=0\iff\cos\Bigl(2\theta-\frac\pi4\Bigr)=\frac1{5\sqrt2}\\
&\iff 2\theta-\frac\pi4\equiv\pm\arccos\frac1{5\sqrt2}\mod2\pi\\
&\iff \theta\equiv\frac\pi8\pm\frac12\arccos\frac1{5\sqrt2}\mod\pi.
\end{align*}

*A shorter method:*

First observe we cannot have $\cos\theta=0$, for it would imply $\sin\theta=0$ and we cannot have both. So we can divide the equation by $ \cos\theta$, obtaining:
$$3\tan^2\theta+5\tan\theta-2=0$$
Now the quadratic equation $t^2+5t-2=0$ has discriminant equal to $49$ and  roots $\;\Bigl\{-2,\dfrac13\Bigr\}$. Thus we have to solve
$$\begin{cases}\tan\theta=-2\\\tan\theta=\dfrac13\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}\theta\equiv-\arctan2\mod\pi\\\theta\equiv\arctan\dfrac13\mod\pi=\dfrac\pi2-\arctan 3\mod\pi\end{cases}$$

Comment: this is too superb for my standard. I do appreciate alternative methods.

Comment: @NubPro: I added another solution. Please see if if is more suitable.

Comment: Definitely. Thanks!

Comment: I think the short method here is the best way to tackle this problem down.

Answer (score 0):

$3\sin^2{\theta}-2\cos^2{\theta}+5\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}=0$
Transfer the $\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}$ term to the RHS.
$3\sin^2{\theta}-2\cos^2{\theta}=-5\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta} $
Then square both sides.
$(3\sin^2{\theta}-2\cos^2{\theta})^2=(-5\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta})^2$
$9\sin^4{\theta}-12\sin^2{\theta}\cos^2{\theta}+4\cos^4{\theta}=25\sin^2{\theta}\cos^2{\theta}$
Then convert all occurrences of $\sin^2{\theta}$ to $1-\cos^2{\theta}$.
$9(1-\cos^2{\theta})^2-12(1-\cos^2{\theta})\cos^2{\theta}+4\cos^4{\theta}=(1-\cos^2{\theta})\cos^2{\theta}$
This will give an equation which can be solved for $\cos^2{\theta}$,
$50\cos^4{\theta}-55\cos^2{\theta}+9=0$
then for $\cos{\theta}$,
then for $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Factorise this into the quadratic:

$$3 \sin^2 \theta + 5 \sin \theta \cos \theta - 2\cos^2 \theta = 0$$

$$(3 \sin \theta - \cos \theta )(sin \theta + 2\cos \theta) = 0$$

This gives 2 equations.

$$3 \sin \theta - \cos \theta = 0$$
$$\sin \theta + 2\cos \theta = 0$$

You should be able to solve it by dividing both by cos. And then solve for tan.

(Make sure you check the cases if $$\cos \theta = 0$$ separately afterwards to see if you missed any solutions when dividing by cos)

Comment: My apologies, got the signs wrong on the 1st answer. Edited it.

Comment: What do you mean by checking the cases?

Comment: Typo in your fourth equation.

Comment: Dividing by cos means that you will miss any solutions when cos theta = 0. To avoid this, just simply see what happens if cos theta = 0 in the original equation. If cos theta = 0 works to solve the equation, then it is a solution. If not, then you haven't missed any extra solutions (Note that in this case, cos theta = 0 means that sin theta = 1, in which case you won't get any extra solutions)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **general** strategy dealing with these kind of problems. **Using summation formulas for sin and cos** one can easily prove the following identities

$$\left\{ \matrix{
  \cos 2\theta  = {\cos ^2}\theta  - {\sin ^2}\theta  = 2{\cos ^2}\theta  - 1 = 1 - 2{\sin ^2}\theta  \hfill \cr 
  \sin 2\theta  = 2\sin \theta \cos \theta  \hfill \cr}  \right.$$

using these you can write

$$\eqalign{
  & {\cos ^2}\theta  = {{1 + \cos 2\theta } \over 2}  \cr 
  & {\sin ^2}\theta  = {{1 - \cos 2\theta } \over 2}  \cr 
  & \sin \theta \cos \theta  = {{\sin 2\theta } \over 2} \cr} $$

put these into your equation to get

$$3\left( {{{1 - \cos 2\theta } \over 2}} \right) + 5\left( {{{\sin 2\theta } \over 2}} \right) - 2\left( {{{1 + \cos 2\theta } \over 2}} \right) = 0$$

simplify to get

$$\eqalign{
  & {1 \over 2} - {5 \over 2}\cos 2\theta  + {5 \over 2}\sin 2\theta  = 0  \cr 
  & \sin 2\theta  - \cos 2\theta  + {1 \over 5} = 0 \cr} $$

the next step is to combine linear combinations of $\sin 2\theta $ and $\cos 2\theta $. You can do this again using **summation formulas**

$$\left\{ \matrix{
  \sin x + w\cos x = \sin x + \tan \alpha \cos x = {1 \over {\cos \alpha }}\left( {\sin x\cos \alpha  + \sin \alpha \cos x} \right) = {1 \over {\cos \alpha }}\sin \left( {x + \alpha } \right) \hfill \cr 
  \tan \alpha  = w \hfill \cr}  \right.$$

In this case

$$\tan \alpha  =  - 1\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\alpha  = {{3\pi } \over 4}\,\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\,\cos \alpha  =  - {1 \over {\sqrt 2 }}$$

and hence you can write

$$ - \sqrt 2 \sin (2\theta  + {{3\pi } \over 4}) + {1 \over 5} = 0$$

or

$$\sin (2\theta  + {{3\pi } \over 4}) = {1 \over {5\sqrt 2 }}$$

and hence

$$2\theta  + {{3\pi } \over 4} = \left\{ \matrix{
  \arcsin \left( {{1 \over {5\sqrt 2 }}} \right) \hfill \cr 
  \pi  - \arcsin \left( {{1 \over {5\sqrt 2 }}} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right. + 2n\pi \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,n = 1,2,3,...$$

which finally gives

$$\theta  = {1 \over 2}\left( {\left\{ \matrix{
  \arcsin \left( {{1 \over {5\sqrt 2 }}} \right) \hfill \cr 
  \pi  - \arcsin \left( {{1 \over {5\sqrt 2 }}} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right. + 2n\pi  - {{3\pi } \over 4}} \right)$$

Comment: Well, unfortunately my studies doesn't cover thoroughly at this point.

Comment: you mean you don't know summation formulas for sin and cos? The base of all I have used are these formulas. :)

Comment: arcsin thingy..

Comment: As an example, how do you solve $sin(x)=0.1$?

Comment: omg.....I figured out what arcsin is. XD This is embarrassing. Do you pronounce it as "ARC SIN" or "INVERSE SIN"?

Comment: both are the same! :) Also, you can vote up the whole answers while you cannot tick all of them. :)

Comment: yea i did, unfortunately...again...I would need at least 15 reps in this community. 7 reps left to go.

Answer (score 0):

Following excellent advice by @raul, you write immediately

$$\tan(\theta)=\frac{-5\pm\sqrt{5^2+4\cdot3\cdot2}}{2\cdot3}=\frac13,-2.$$

Comment: yup...my bad...